# image compression in jmagick

Tags: java, jmagick

I am writing a program in Java using JMagick, and I need to be able to compress the image(lower the filesize) by lowering the quality of the image. I have tried the info.setQuality(99) and info.setQuality(1) classes but there is no difference in the size of the outputfile.

Is there a way to increase and decrease the quality of the image and thus adjusting the filesize of the outputfile with JMagick?

Thanks in advance.
Sorry for the bad formatting.

```
    import java.io.*;
    import magick.*;
    public class jpgconverter {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws MagickException 
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MagickException, IOException {
    int pixels = 500;
    ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo("/home/bram/Downloads/verborgenlagen.jpg");
        MagickImage converter = new MagickImage(info);
        double currentHeight = converter.getDimension().getHeight();
        double currentWidth = converter.getDimension().getWidth();
        if(currentWidth > currentHeight) {
            currentHeight = currentHeight * pixels / currentWidth;
            currentWidth = pixels;
        }else {
            if(currentHeight > currentWidth) {
                currentWidth = currentWidth * pixels / currentHeight;
                currentHeight = pixels;
            }
        }
        converter.setXResolution(72.00);
        converter.setYResolution(72.00);
    converter = converter.scaleImage((int)currentWidth, (int)currentHeight);
    converter.setFileName("/home/bram/Downloads/verborgenlagenConverted.jpg");
    converter.writeImage(info);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can share the code for reference?

Comment: How did you fix it?